# Internet explorer CSS zoom ignores max-width and max-height

Tags: css, internet-explorer

CSS:

```
.absolute-centered {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    zoom: 10
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://funnyasduck.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Internet-Explorer-Meme.jpg" class="absolute-centered" />
```

It appears that IE (9, 10) ignores `max-width` and `max-height`. Why that's happening?

JSFiddle also available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f8uqF/2/).

Answer (score 1):

`max-width` and `max-height` correspond to the parent element. For example:

```
#parent{
    width:500px;
    max-width:500px;
    height:100px;
    max-height:100px;
    background:#FF0000;
}
.child{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

There are many ways of positioning an image into the centre of an element, but without seeing your parent element I can't suggest what method would be best.
For Div's I've used:

```
div#parent{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:#FF0000;
}
div#parent>img.child /*your child element*/{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    margin:auto;
    background:#00FF00;
}
```

bare in mind though that margins and paddings can throw off positioning, widths and heights. Some elements (divs) require content to be 'visible'. Using a `position:absolute;` will position the element relative to it's static position and I don't think you want to use this to position an image in the centre. Another suggestion is that if your parent element is a fixed pixel size, why not make the child image the same size? Or use the image as the parent's background image?

Comment: thanks you for your response but parent element could be any size. All that I expect is to display image exactly in the center of that container and if the image is too small the zoom it not more than 10 times. So if you will open http://jsfiddle.net/f8uqF/2/ in normal browser you can see that image positioned at the center of result container (horizontally and vertically) but if you open that in IE you will see only part of 10 times zoomed image

Comment: @Vladimirs Not too sure what to suggest. I'd heard zoom was an old ie 'hack', never used it myself. My guess would be ie9+ depreciated it. Other browsers don't seem to use it. I'd personally just give the parent a set `height` and `width` then give the image `min-height` and `min-width` both of 100% setting the image dead in the parent's sizing parameters. Here's a link of a more advanced look at zoom. Which I believe you've set zoom too 1000% (only skimmed the article) 
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/